# YAML anchors for PowerShell scripts

Tags: powershell, gitlab, yaml

I have YAML file for GitLab CI/CD Pipeline

```
.myanchor: &myanchor
  - 'echo "Some Test"'

My Job:
  script:
    - 'echo "Some Text"'
    - '*myanchor'
```

When I run pipeline, I get an error "myanchor : The term '*myanchor' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

I tried removing quotes in a string - '*myanchor' but then CLint says that YAML is incorrect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This suggests that PowerShell tried to execute `*myanchor` _as a command_. Please clarify - by directly updating your question - what the intended behavior is.

Comment: The expected behavior is that the code from the anchor is added to the script section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'*myanchor'` is a YAML scalar and will be loaded as string. If you want to refer to the node with the anchor `&myanchor`, you must not use quotes.

If you drop the quotes, the structure in `My Job` will be

```yaml
My Job:
  script:
    - 'echo "Some Text"'
    - - 'echo "Some Text"'
```

It is likely that nested sequences are not supported for the content of `script:` (this is not a limitation of YAML per se, but a limitation of the tool that processes this structure).

To fix it, you need to put the anchor on the sequence item instead of the list:

```yaml
.myanchor:
  - &myanchor 'echo "Some Test"'

My Job:
  script:
    - 'echo "Some Text"'
    - *myanchor
```

Now the problem is probably that you want to reference multiple items with `*myanchor` and put each of them as item directly into the `script:` sequence. That is simply not possible with YAML so you need to find another solution – perhaps preprocessing your YAML with a templating engine (lots of YAML's heavy users like e.g. Ansible and SaltStack do this).